# What is the best way of deleting a section of a binary file in Java 7

Tags: java, nio

i.e I have a 10 mb file, and I want to remove bytes 1M to 2M so the resultant file is 9mb, with the data that was starting at 2m bytes into the file now starting at 1M

Im using Java 7 so can make of NIO, files typically 10MB in size and often accessed over the network so Im looking for an elegant solution that performs well.

Im aware of BteBuffer.allocateDirect() and File.getChannel() but Im struggling to work out if there is way to do what I want which doesnt involve having to write 8MB from file channel to a temporary buffer just in order to write it back to file in a different place, or is this actually okay if using allocateDirect()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of using a temporary file on disk is a good approach, I think.  If you are in the situation where you can create a new temporary file on disk, then nio does have some options that may help you.  I'm just going off of the API here and the nio tutorial, but it seems that `FileChannel.transferFrom` or `FileChannel.transferTo` may be the tools you need.

I have not tested the following code, but it should point you in the right direction.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int megaByte = 1024 * 1024;
    // prepare the paths
    Path inPath = Paths.get("D:/file.dat"); // java.nio.file.Paths
    Path outPath; // java.nio.file.Path
    try {
        outPath = Files.createTempFile(null, "swp"); // java.nio.file.Files
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IOError(ex);
    }

    // process the file
    try (
            FileChannel readChannel = new FileChannel.open(inPath, READ);
            FileChannel writeChannel = new FileChannel.open(outPath, WRITE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING)
    ) {
        long readFileSize = readChannel.size();
        long expectedWriteSize = readFileSize;
        if (readFileSize > 2 * megabyte)
            expectedWriteSize = readFileSize - megabyte;
        else if (readFileSize > megabyte)
            expectedWriteSize = megabyte;
        // copy first megabyte (or entire file if less than a megabyte)
        long bytesTrans = readChannel.transferTo(0, megabyte, writeChannel);
        // copy everything after the second megabyte
        if (readFileSize > 2 * megabyte)
            bytesTrans += readChannel.transferTo(2 * megabyte, readFileSize - 2 * megabyte, writeChannel);
        if (bytesTrans != expectedWriteSize)
            System.out.println("WARNING: Transferred " + bytesTrans + " bytes instead of " + expectedWriteSize);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("File not found!", ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Caught IOException", ex);
    }

    // replace the original file with the temporary file
    try {
        // ATOMIC_MOVE may cause IOException here . . .
        Files.move(outPath, inPath, REPLACE_EXISTING, ATOMIC_MOVE);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        try {
            // . . . so it's probably worth trying again without that option
            Files.move(outPath, inPath, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            throw new IOError(e2);
        }
    }
}
```

It's possible that nio would help even if you cannot open a new file.  If you open a read/write channel to a file or open two different channels on the same file, it may work to transfer one portion of the file to another portion of the file with the `transferTo` method.  I don't have enough experience with it to know.  The API states that a method that takes an explicit position argument (like the first argument of `transferTo`) can proceed concurrently with an operation that writes to a file, so I wouldn't rule it out.  You might want to rewrite the file in megabyte size chunks if you try that.  If that does work, then `FileChannel.truncate` could be used to chop off the last megabyte of the file when you are finished writing portions of the file to one megabyte earlier position in the file.

Comment: It seems reading/writing to same file using transferTo does indeed work on Windows but not on OSX :(

Comment: Okay doesnt tell me much I dont know but I think this is the best of the answers

Comment: I noticed that inPath has to be closed [readChannel.close()] before performing the move. Well, this was certainly the case for me on a Win10 machine.

Answer (score 3):

Write the result to a temporary file, then replace the old file with your temporary file (which acts as a buffer on disk).

**Code example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // -- prepare files
    File inFile = new File("D:/file.dat");
    File outFile;
    try {
        outFile = File.createTempFile("swap", "buffer");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IOError(ex);
    }

    // -- process file
    try (
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile)
    ) {
        //drop some bytes      (will be removed)
        inStream.skip(4);
        //modify some bytes    (will be changed)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            byte b = (byte) inStream.read();
            outStream.write(b >> 4);
        }
        //copy bytes in chunks (will be kept)
        final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] chunkBuffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        while (true) {
            int chunkSize = inStream.read(chunkBuffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
            if (chunkSize < 0) {
                break;
            }
            outStream.write(chunkBuffer, 0, chunkSize);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("input file not found!", ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("failed to trim data!", ex);
    }

    // -- release changes
    //replace inFile with outFile
    inFile.delete();
    outFile.renameTo(inFile);
}
```

Comment: You might want to point out that the main advantage of this over the approach in the question, is that it's safe, i.e. if the system crashes halfway through the process, the original data is not lost/corrupted.

Comment: Actually, my point was to leave the choice of exception handling to OP, so declare `throws` and don't handle any exceptions in code sample. Keeps the sample clean and on point.

Comment: I think it would be better to use ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() rather than byte arrays to bypass the heap wouldnt it ? But your point about writing to a new file is sensible, although in the past i have had issues with users having their system setup to allow files to be edited but not for a new files to be created and this has caused issues. Also if the file is on a network drive is it better for the temporary file to also be on the network drive or on the local drive ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think You can read a huge file into memory and just chop off some segment of it. @Binkan's approach is much smarter as this one has been tested for file of upto 15MB

```
    try {
        // read the file 
        byte[] results = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("xfile.apk"));
        // strip off say 1MB
        byte[] trimmed = Arrays.copyOfRange(results, 0,
                (results.length / (1024 * 1024)) - 1);
        Files.write(Paths.get("xfile.apk"), trimmed,
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Perhaps using a [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html)could give performance overheads

Comment: So your approach is simply to read the whole file into memory and then use that to write new contents back to file. I think it would be better to ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() so that I do not use up valuable heap space, especially if a number of files are open at the same time - maybe that would work nicely. I thought it would be a waste to read the whole 15mb into a buffer but perhaps that is the best solution. I dont think a MappedByteBuffer would really help since it is a view of the file I dont think I can delete/shift data so I need a copy of the data I want to keep.